# How to edit docker file of the image which is pulled from registry?

Tags: dockerfile

I have pulled one image from registry.
I am able to see image using following command :

```
$docker images
```

But I am not able to edit its Dockerfile.

Answer (score 1):

You can grab the dockerFile from hub.docker.com -> search the image you want,
Download it make your modification and build it, or run the image downloaded and make your modification, commit it and push it on your docker hub account.
Hope this will help you.